# Different ViewControllers in iOS-Slide-Menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, hamburger-menu

I am using the [aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu](https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu). My problem is: I need to show different left menus depending on which View Controller is being shown. This is my code in the AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
 UserMenuViewController *leftMenu = (UserMenuViewController *) [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UserMenuViewController"];


    [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].leftMenu = leftMenu;
```

When I try to change the left menu in my special ViewController, I get a black screen in the left menu.

```
AppDelegate *sharedeDelegate = ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate);

    ProfessionalMenuViewController *leftMenu = (ProfessionalMenuViewController *) [sharedeDelegate.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfessionalMenuViewController"];
    [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].leftMenu = leftMenu;
```

I Tried a lot of things, but nothing worked. Thanks!

Comment: Make UserMenuViewController *leftMenu a property in AppDelegate.h. Initiate it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions as self.leftMenu = [whatever you want].  in Other Viewcontrollers, access the Appdelegate and set it like sharedDelegate.leftMenu = [whatever]. A question though, why are you using it in AppDelegate? Why not use it as member of VCs since the functionality is different on different VCs?

Comment: If I move it from the app delegate, I get the black screen.

Comment: @RenanGelrado, did you try what i suggested?

Comment: @NSNoob, yes I did, but didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know only one solution:

```
 AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];

SlideNavigationController* landingScreen = (SlideNavigationController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"SlideNavigationController"];
LeftMenuViewController *leftMenu = (LeftMenuViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"CVLeftMenuViewController"];

landingScreen.leftMenu = leftMenu;
landingScreen.enableShadow=YES;
landingScreen.enableSwipeGesture = YES;
landingScreen.panGestureSideOffset = 0;

delegate.window.rootViewController = landingScreen;
```

Need update SlideNavigationController see landingScreen(i used when change language without rebooting app)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that customize leftMenuViewController, Set one global variable and show different tableview content in left menu depending on the value of global variable, or handle SlideNavigationControllerDidReveal notification in leftMenuViewController and add any subview or remove subview based on your currently opened sideview controller.